# WebDriver and IE10 very slow input

Tags: java, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When I'm trying to execute tests in the latest IE, I see that input is very slow : it takes like 5 seconds for every character to appear in the input field.
All security zones are enabled and the driver initialized with the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./src/test/resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
return new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

This problem appears only on IE10 ; when I'm running Firefox everything is just fine.

My OS is Windows 8, just in case.

Did I miss something?

**UPD** Now i can see that sometimes IE works faster, but when it happens this code doesn't work:

```
action.contextClick(logoPic).clickAndHold().sendKeys("keys_to_invoke_some_window").perform();
```

Comment: Tried, no changes. Also tried on Windows 7 x32 with IE 8 - everything works well, so i suppose the problem is in Windows 8 x64 or in latest IE

Comment: I think you should compare the performance with another version of the Internet Explorer, since the drivers for those and Firefox are different.

Comment: As far as i know it is impossible to downgrade IE on Win 8, as i write before on Win 7 and IE 8 it works fine.

Comment: The problem is registered as [issue#3072](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3072).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fixed by replacing IEDriverServer.exe (switched from x64 version to x32 version)

Comment: Solved the issue for Windows7 64bit and IE10

Comment: Solved - Windows 8, IE10. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.3.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: This works because even though you're on a 64 bit machine, it has 32 bit Internet Explorer installed and that works best with the 32 bit WebDriver.

Answer (score -4):

Replacing the IEDriverServer.exe(switched from x64 version to x32 version) solved the issue of slowness.

Comment: -1 because this is the same as the accepted answer

Comment: same answer as accepted one