# Unable to find element on closed window on IE 11 with Selenium

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to run tests on Internet Explorer 11 working with Selenium WebDriver.
The code is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Path/to//IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

And I get this error:

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
>   2.46.0.0 Listening on port 43760 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on
>   closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.46.0', revision:
>   '61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04
>   10:22:50' System info: host: 'user1-PC', ip: '10.0.23.71', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_45' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true,
>   ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true,
>   ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0,
>   ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false,
>   browserName=internet explorer,
>   initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:43760/, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,
>   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}] Session ID:
>   8a5b7ab5-862a-462d-ab4b-929d4ed5b71a
>   *** Element info: {Using=name, value=q}   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:358)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:431)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:300)   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:350)
>     at MySel20Proj.MySel20Proj.App.main(App.java:42)

I tried to follow the configure tutorial on https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver but is still not working. And this code works on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: did the script opened the IE browser?

Comment: Yes, the script opens the IE browser, the exception is when it has to find the element q (the search textbox)

Comment: I tried it on Selenium Build #2.44 and it worked fine. Please downgrade your selenium version

Comment: Do you mean the IE webdriver version o Selenium version?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous statement. I reffered to IE webdriver version

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is the same, the exception is still appearing.

Comment: did you set registry entry?

Comment: Yes, I did, I created the FEATURE_BFCACHE and inside I created a DWORD value named iexplorer.exe with value 0x0000000 (0)

Comment: The IEDriver is opening.Is it not even navigating to the url or not finding the elements only

Comment: It does navigate to the URL, but it doesn't find the element.

Comment: Same problem. Browser opens, loads the page, but then throws when trying to find an element on Windows 10, IE11 (with Dart language Selenium client)

Comment: What solution you found @Alex I am having same issue.

Comment: Someone has found the solution, I have exactly the same issue. I open the IE11 Driver, it navigate to the URL. I have use the same configuration Windows 10, IE11, Selenium 3.0.1 and IEBrowserDriver 3.0.0. There is no one 3.0.1 version

Answer (score 33):

Try going to Internet Options --> Security --> "Enable Protected Mode" on **ALL** zones should either be checked or **ALL** unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Does somebody know WHY this is?

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways:

**Way 1:** Setting INITIAL_BROWSER_URL:

```
File ieFile = new File("D:\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieFile.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities ieCaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://www.bing.com/");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCaps);
//some operations on that site
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q")).sendKeys("Ripon Al Wasim");
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_go")).click();
```

**Way 2:** To set a registry entry on the target computer:
For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain
a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.

*For 32-bit Windows:* The key you must examine in the registry editor is
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

*For 64-bit Windows:* The key is
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present.
Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

For more details you can visit:  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: This is the main focus:   ieCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://www.bing.com/");

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue after going through every possible solution finally I got the answer.Try this it will definitely solve your problem as well.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");

capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C://MavenTest//driver//IEDriverServer.exe");

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

**For 32-bit Windows:** The key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

**For 64-bit Windows:** The key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue. I faced while I was running my code in the Maven build. Here in the POM XML file,  I had a different version whereas actual selenium installed is  another version. So just changed the version so that it matches with the installed version. And Now everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

Ripon Al Wasim posted this url, which is a key to IE11 working with Selenium.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

I had this setup:

- Windows 7 Pro 64 bit
- IE11 64 bit, latest I found
- Selenium remote server 2.53.1 64 bit
- IEDriverServer 2.53.1 64 bit
- selenium 2.53.1 module installed on 64 bit linux machine used with 64 bit python

downloaded from here: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/

I had to follow the guide and to:

- Set Enhanced Protected Mode to disabled in all security zones which is a requirement for IE10 and IE11.
- Add the `FEATURE_BFCACHE` key and it's `iexplore.exe` DWORD into registry
- I made all used software to be 64 bit.
- Check that zoom in IE is set to 100%.
- Check if size of text is 100% in Windows display settings.

Additionaly:

- I had to disable proxy settings in IE, because it prevented `Selenium remote server` to communicate with `IEDriverServer`.
- I am running webdriver with `requireWindowFocus` set to true, because key typing  with 64 bit selenium was slow due some timeout issue ([Selenium WebDriver typing very slow in text field on IE browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985300/selenium-webdriver-typing-very-slow-in-text-field-on-ie-browser))

And it worked. I divert from the guide when I specify a path to IEDriverServer.exe when I run standalone server, so it doesn't necessary have to be in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Same exception, but in Python. This worked for me:

```
delay = 30
driver.implicitly_wait(delay)
```