# Internet Explorer hangs when ran through selenium webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

When running the test in internet explorer , after the home page is loaded , it just hangs/ become unresponsive.

- Selenium version : 2.53
- Windows server 2012 OS
- Internet explorer 11

Changed security settings in Internet options still no use.

Observation : Sometimes by changing some security settings , says **there is no such element with partial text is present**. But same code runs fine in both `firefox` and `chrome`.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint right before the home page is loaded then step through the code.

Comment: manually is it loading properly.. is there any script errors on IE console.

Comment: Manually it is loading properly .. not seeing any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens when you download 32 bit IE driver server and use it on 64 bit OS or Vice-versa. As this can be a point of Issue so I suggest you to download latest IE driver of relative 32 or 64 bit.

Follow the url to download IE driver:

Visit: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: But if I use 64 bit IE driver , typing in text field through automation is entering single letter by letter..and yes my system is 64 bit.

Comment: Using 64 bit ..It's navigating to next page , as explained above its entering letter by letter in the user name field . can you please suggest alternative to solve this using 64 bit IE ?

Comment: @Rahul Check the second answer in the [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985300/selenium-webdriver-typing-very-slow-in-text-field-on-ie-browser). Hope it might help you.

Comment: @Sudeepthi : DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();   capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);        using 32 bit IE and changing the settings in IE , Advanced tab , enabling enhanced protected mode worked for me !!! , Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Rahul Great that it worked and you solved your issue. Can you upvote my answer if you think that helped you.