# Selenium IE Webdriver send slowkeys even though changed to 32Bit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I have a serious Problem, and i tried about 20 workarounds which completely failed to work as a solution for me.

**MainProblem:** I execute a testsuite parallel on 3 different browsers, Chrome, Firefox and IE11. While **sendKeys()** works perfectly fine on chrome and Firefox, on IE every letter takes about 5 seconds to appear, so a normal login-procedure which takes about 2 sec on chrome takes about 50 on IE...

I work on a mac. On the Mac, i have a WindowsPC (Win10) in a VM via Parallels. On this, i installed JDK, Eclipse, and try to automate a webpage via Selenium+Testng.

IE Version: 11.192.16299.0

I set the security level to low for trusted and local intranet, i removed the save-mode checkbox. I got the well known slow-sendKeys-Problem. But for most of the internet it worked with changing the IEWebdriver from 64-> 32Bit. It simply doesnt make any difference and i struggle here. 
I really need help. Please let me know if you need any insight, logs or whatever, i try to provide with everything fast.

Best Greets!

Comment: could you specify your issue without mess with environment. Just what does not work? I understand that your description could be very helpful in findeng solution, but I don't understand what doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i updated the post (first time stackoverflow-poster^^)

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985300/selenium-webdriver-typing-very-slow-in-text-field-on-ie-browser

Comment: I tried every of the solutions, and only one worked PARTLY for me..
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

Problem: in the last line, the InternetExplorerDriver is crossed out, because its deprecated. Cant find a "newer" solution to send capabilities with the driver-constructor.
But with that option, it works, it feels very weird, as it takes a few seconds till it paste the keys in, but it works. Still cant overcome that deprecatedwarning

Comment: Use the internetexploreroptions as parameter constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting up the following options It should resolve the problem:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./path/IEDriverServer.exe");

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();
options.requireWindowFocus();

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Comment: That´s it! Thank you very much!