# Detecting angularJS elements in IE11 browser using selenium takes long time. How to resolve this?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

I'm running selenium tests on IE 11 in angularJS application. It takes more than usual time to detect/select/validate elements while it works better in chrome.

Browser information : Internet explorer 11
Webdriver : IEdriverserver 32bit
selenium version: 3.14

Comment: This is the problem of IE, chrome is faster

Comment: My requirement is to run tests in IE. Isn't there any way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following methods to make it faster when using selenium IE WebDriver:

1. Download the recommended **32 bit** Windows **IE WebDriver version 3.150.1** 
   and latest stable **version 3.141.59 of Selenium** from [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
2. Change your IE settings: Tools -> Internet Options -> Security, set **Enable Protected Mode** to the same value in all zones (all checked or all unchecked).

[image]

3. Instantiate your `InterExplorerWeDriver` class with the path of your IE WebDriver like this:

   ```
   InternetExplorerDriver ieDiver = new InternetExplorerDriver(“Path to the 32 bit IEdriver”);
   ```
4. Add capability `nativeEvents` as `false`. Add capability `requireWindowFocus` as `true`.

*Reference link:*

(1) [Very slow text entry on IEDriverServer](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4737#issuecomment-554348158)

(2) [Selenium WebDriver typing very slow in text field on IE browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985300/selenium-webdriver-typing-very-slow-in-text-field-on-ie-browser/279853983#27985398)