# Use of 64 bit Windows IE WebDriver when it type very slow

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently, I got my machine replaced and I had to start installing stuffs all over again. I have 64-bit Windows machine and instead of using 64-bit IE driver, I used 32-bit IE driver. The **reason for using the 32-bit IE driver is obviously the slow typing issue in 64-bit one**, and switching seems the only option as can be found in below threads.

[Why is Selenium InternetExplorerDriver Webdriver very slow in debug mode (visual studio 2010 and IE9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850211/why-is-selenium-internetexplorerdriver-webdriver-very-slow-in-debug-mode-visual), and 
[WebDriver and IE10 very slow input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461827/webdriver-and-ie10-very-slow-input)

My questions are:

1. Can slow typing issue be solved without really switching to 32-bit IE Driver?
2. What is the need of 64-bit IE driver when it can slow down your tests very much?

On Selenium official [download](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) page, 32-bit is recommended, do we actually require 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can slow typing issue be solved without really switching to 32-bit IE Driver?**

To my knowledge no. I did a benchmarking on login page of my application using 32x vs 64x version. There are significant amount of performance improvement when you use 32x as you know.

**What is the need of 64-bit IE driver when it can slow down your tests very much?**

Couple of reasons why.

- According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c21) thread, the non-truncated screenshot of the page is only possible if you use 64x version of IEDriverServer.
- The 64x of IE8 on windows 7 RTM and IE9 both can be run as 64x application using 64x IEDriverServer. There could be a need to use 64x application for testing purpose.

Comment: Products of Microsoft are quite famous for their notoriety and kind of carved a niche for themselves ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that pretty much points out the difference. There seems to some reason of using 64-bit driver and has a workaround that i mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: A full accounting and technical analysis of the reasons for this behavior can be found at http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c21) shared by @Saifur above, there seems to be the workaround for using 64-bit instead of switching to 32-bit(though I haven't yet tested it and probably never will).

> First, you can disable native events by setting the "nativeEvents"
>   capability to false using whatever mechanism your language binding
>   provides for this.

and,

> A more accurate workaround from an input simulation perspective would
>   be to enable the "requireWindowFocus" capability, though this also has
>   a windows hook dependency, which may manifest in other ways.

Comment: I just tried switching EnableNativeEvents to false and it made a big difference.